# Index Fragmentation Percentage different from script vs. SSMS Client

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using SQL Server 2012 (fully up-to-date). We have been reviewing fragmentation levels using the below script but we're getting very different results from what the SSMS Client shows us. Can someone shed some light on what is going on and which to trust?

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType,
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind 
ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id
AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id
WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > -1--You can specify the percent as you want
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

**Here is a result from running the above script**

[image]

**Here is a result when viewing through the SSMS Client**

[image]

You can see that results are vastly different. This has been observed on both clustered and non-clustered indexes.

If is matters, we update statistics regularly so not sure what is going on and which to trust

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` with a different set of parameters than what SSMS uses.

When you invoke this function you specify a `mode=NULL` parameter, which is the same as `mode='LIMITED'`. If you watch SSMS with SQL Profiler you can see that it supplies a `mode='SAMPLED'` parameter, e.g.:

```sql
select partition_number as PartitionNumber,
    index_type_desc as IndexType,
    index_depth as Depth,
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent    as AverageFragmentation,
    page_count  as Pages,
    avg_page_space_used_in_percent  as AveragePageDensity,
    record_count as Rows,
    ghost_record_count  as GhostRows,
    version_ghost_record_count  as VersionGhostRows,
    min_record_size_in_bytes as MinimumRecordSize,
    max_record_size_in_bytes as MaximumRecordSize,
    avg_record_size_in_bytes as AverageRecordSize,
    forwarded_record_count as ForwardedRecords
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(11, 730589791, 1, NULL, 'SAMPLED')
```

According to [Scanning Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#scanning-modes) (emphasis mine):

> The LIMITED mode is the fastest mode and scans the smallest number of pages. For an index, only the parent-level pages of the B-tree (that is, the pages above the leaf level) are scanned. For a heap, the associated PFS and IAM pages are examined and the data pages of a heap are scanned in LIMITED mode.
>
> With LIMITED mode, compressed_page_count is NULL because the Database Engine only scans non-leaf pages of the B-tree and the IAM and PFS pages of the heap.
>
> Use SAMPLED mode to get an estimated value for compressed_page_count, and use DETAILED mode to get the actual value for compressed_page_count. The SAMPLED mode returns statistics based on a 1 percent sample of all the pages in the index or heap. **Results in SAMPLED mode should be regarded as approximate.**